# Can't install homebrew formula, says "Error: File exists - build"

Tags: homebrew

I am trying to install `wine`, by running `brew install wine`, but it fails. This is the output:

```
==> Installing dependencies for wine: jasper, gmp
==> Installing wine dependency: jasper
==> Using the sandbox
==> Downloading https://github.com/mdadams/jasper/archive/version-2.0.9.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/gustaf/Library/Caches/Homebrew/jasper-2.0.9.tar.gz
Error: File exists - build
```

Both dependencies are already installed.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the file from the cache?

Comment: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/README.md#troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem when I was trying to upgrade `jasper`

The issue appears to be that the formula wants you to build in a subdirectory called `build` but there is already a directory called build in the repository.

My fix was to modify line 21 of the formula.

You can edit the formula with

```
brew edit jasper
```

and change line 21 to read

```
mkdir "build2" do
```

or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, but I solved it while installing the winetricks.

```
brew install winetricks
```

it will install the wine too, but won't report the error on my Mac.